# Java get response code from URL

Tags: java, url

```
while (it.isValid()) {
        SimpleAttributeSet s = (SimpleAttributeSet) it.getAttributes();
        linkURLs = (String) s.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);

        if (linkURLs != null) {

            System.out.println(linkURLs);

        }
        it.next();

    }
```

This loop shows the URLs.

How to display the getResponseCode () for each address? It must be done in a loop?
Can anyone write such code? I do not know how you go about it.

Answer (score 4):

You're going to need to open those URLs, but be warned that they could be relative or protocol-relative (unless your library does this for you).  Once you rebuild the URL, do

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);

// Might be a good idea to validate the connection type before casting
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand what this is all about.